# calculate rotation of two joined lines to reach point with some coordinates

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, geometry

I have two jointed bars, first can spin on 360deg around 0 coords. Second jointed with first, and can rotate on 360 around joint.

Can I calculate how the rotation of both rods should be so that the end of the second one reaches a point with some coordinates

You can write usual geometry formula

[image]

Comment: maybe check this https://robotacademy.net.au/lesson/inverse-kinematics-for-a-2-joint-robot-arm-using-geometry/) out. If it is not helping may search for inverse kinematics. What you want to do is a typical simple example which can be calculated easily by hand. One time in a robotics class i had to do the same, but was a while ago not sure what the excact steps and resulting formular was

Comment: THANKS IT IS WHAT I NEED! 
Im doing robotic arm in the game

Comment: Well there are probably multiple possible solutions for the same target point .. inverse kinematics is probably what you want to go for